# Is it normal to say "greater extreme"?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

> Some animals have taken cooperation to even greater extreme. (BBC
>   documentary, journey of life)

I doubt that “extreme” is subject to comparison with other extreme. An extreme is a polar point. So is the expression here a bit poetic, therefore attracting unnecessary attention for words?

Comment: Even scientists and statisticians talk about "local maxima", etc.

Comment: It shold be "to even greater extremes" or "to an even greater extreme"

Comment: it sounds to me - an acute crisis.

Answer (score 5):

*Extreme* has been used in a non-absolute sense, hence allowing *greater*, *greatest*, *more* or *most* for a long time. (And likewise, *lesser*, etc.)

Indeed, the earliest example I see of it cited, in English, in **any** sense uses it with most:

> Lyvyn in the most extreme Povertie. — Sir John Fortescue, *The governance of England: otherwise called The difference between an absolute and a limited monarchy*, c1460

As such "greater extreme" which starts from something which is very far away from a norm, and then compares something even more so, is perfectly within normal usage.

Answer (score 2):

One place where "greater extreme" appears to serve as an indisputably legitimate comparative is in mathematical texts. One early example involving this usage is from Alexander Malcolm, [*A New Treatise of Arithmetick and Book-Keeping*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Fd1JAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA27&dq=%22Divide+the+greater+extreme%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nea2VISKKMj78QXbl4DYBQ&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22Divide%20the%20greater%20extreme%22&f=false) (1718):

> You may find the Estate, by finding the eldest Son's Portion, and then the Sum, agreeable to the Rule ; and you may often find this without producing them all, if you divide the greater Extreme by the lesser, and then take the Ratio and multiply it by it self till the Product is equal to the said Quote ; for that Product is a Term in a Rank of the same ratio, whereby a Thing is clear ; ...

Here, the extremes involved are extremes (that is, endpoints) in a geometrical progression, the greater being the highest number and the lesser the lowest. John Newton uses the same wording in the context of logic in [*An Introduction to the Art of Logick*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5KE4AQAAMAAJ&q=%22greater+extreme+the+lesser+extreme%22&dq=%22greater+extreme+the+lesser+extreme%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ney2VMKQNITMmAWp74DgBw&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA) (1671):

> A *nominal definition is the conclusion of the* [?] *of the demonstration : A causal is the beginning: A total is an intire or whole demonstration, differing in nothing from it, but the placing of the terms*: for the thing *defined* is the *greater extreme*, the *lesser extreme* the *subject*, and the *cause* the *middle term*.

The first match in a Google Books search for "greater extreme" outside the areas of mathematics and logic, however, is from much later. From [*The Westminster Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=H4tFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA347&dq=%22greater+extreme%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yfG2VIumOsKNmwW7joCwBg&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAg) (1781) [snippet view]:

> I do not pretend to say that this kind of Vanity is peculiar to women, though it is certainly more general in them, and usually carried to a greater extreme than by the other sex.

Other, similar instances appear in the search results from slightly younger publications. So we're looking at at least 234 years of attested usage of "greater extreme" in the sense of "greater degree."

On the other hand, for the period 1800 through 2008, the occurrences of "greater extreme" (blue line) very nearly flatline in comparison to the occurrences of "greater extent" (red line):

[image]

This suggests to me that some instances of "greater extreme" may be misstatements of "greater extent" or at least instances where "greater extent" has influenced the alteration of "to an extreme" into "to a greater extreme." The BBC documentary that the OP cites is a case in point. The transcript would have read just as clearly if it had said

> Some animals have taken cooperation to an extreme.

or

> Some animals have taken cooperation to an even greater extent.

where (as *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* says) *extent* can be taken to mean "the point, degree, or limit to which something extends." But the scriptwriter either split the difference between those to options or simply preferred the sound of "to even greater extreme." That decision, as Jon Hanna notes in his answer, is not outlandish by any means (or extremes).